# How do you insert this symbol |0| using finale v 26?

Tags: notation, chant

What does this symbol mean |O| ?
It appears in notation for a chanted psalm.
Is there a way to insert this symbol using Finale v 26?

Comment: Do you have a picture of  it? It sounds like it's just a double whole note which you can insert like you do other notes you just have to select that duration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_whole_note

Answer (score 1):

The symbol is called a *double whole note* or *breve* and is double the length of a whole-note (i.e., eight beats in 4/4 time).

In Finale, a double whole note can be entered using ALT+8. See the below image from [the manual](https://usermanuals.finalemusic.com/Finale2012Win/Content/Finale/Keyboard_Shortcuts_and_Special_Mouse_Clicks.htm#XREF_Simple_Entry_Tool_keycuts).

[image: Finale note entry keyboard shortcuts]

Comment: For graphical representation, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_whole_note#/media/File:Breve_notation.svg)